# TableView Cells / Visual Format Language / Keeps adding same constraints?

Tags: swift, uitableview, visual-format-language

Creating UITableViewCells including elements programmatically seems to be working except for the constraints. Or maybe it is. **Everytime the cell reappears the same constraints will be added to the element.** I'll have 20 of the same constraints added to a uiLabel after scrolling tableView. Here is my sublcass (condensed):

```
class TimeSlotCell: UITableViewCell {

let lblTime = UILabel()

var viewCons = [String:AnyObject]()
var previousCageView:UIView!
var myConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()


func configureCell(row:Int,cageCount:Int) {

    lblTime.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addSubview(lblTime)

    placeConstraint("H:|-5-[time\(row)]", view:"time\(row)")
    placeConstraint("V:|-17-[time\(row)]", view: "time\(row)
} 

func placeConstraint(format:String, view:String) {
    viewCons[view] = lblTime
    let navViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(format, options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewCons)
            myConstraints += navViewConstraint
            NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(myConstraints)
   }
```

And in my VC i'm calling the configureCell func within my cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Is there a way to check if an existing constraint exists? Is there a way to make sure only one of my constraints can be added? Or is there a person out there with a much better solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep. Placing the addSubview and constraints in initializer worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dataSource for your tableView, when you configure your cell,  you send the cell model to your cell. Whenever the dataSource changes, the cell model sent to the cell will change as well. So what you need to do is move most of 'addSubview' to the cell`s initialization. If you have to do cell.contentView.addSubview with the cell model. You have to judge if the cell model you send to the cell is the same as the former one. If it is equal, do nothing, else reset the view config.